# mersenne twister - is there a way to jump to a particular state?

Tags: algorithm, random, mersenne-twister

I am a little unsure about the right forum for this question. It is between theoretical comp. sci./math and programming.

I use Mersenne-Twister to generate pseudo random numbers. Now, starting from a given seed, I would like to jump to the n-th number in the sequence.

I have seen this: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wagnerr/MersenneTwister.html, and one scheme could be as follows:

Suppose, I need only the first *N* numbers in the complete random sequence from particular seed *s*.
I split the sequence in to *p* subsequences, march through all the N numbers, and save the state vector of the random number generator at the beginning of each subsequence.
Now to reach *n*-th number, I'll see that *n* falls in the *k*-th subsequence and I'll load the state vector for this subsequence and generate *m* consecutive random numbers where  m-th number in k-th subsequence is the same as n-th number in the complete sequence ( n = m + (k-1) * N/p ).

But the state vector is 624 x 4 bytes long! I wonder if it is practically possible to jump to an arbitrary element in the mersenne-twister generated sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible! It's called **Jump Ahead**.

You can find all the details to do this with Mersenne Twister on the homepage of MT's authors. Code is available as well as scientific publications explaining the algorithm:

http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/JUMP/index.html

Comment: How high are the memory and CPU requirements? If it's not too much, maybe Python could [reinstate](http://bugs.python.org/issue9816#msg115990) its `jumpahead()` function for its `random` module.

Comment: It's nothing huge. It's just about multiplying matrices. The original paper (http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/ARTICLES/jump-seta-lfsr.pdf) states that jumpahead for MT19937 (the most common declination so probably the one you have in Python I assume) would take 6.692 seconds on an old Intel Core 2 Duo. You can expect something under a second using nowadays architectures.

Answer (score 4):

Today, there is a way to do this using [discard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/discard/). The complexity is linear in number of equivalent advances.

A working example:

```
  std::mt19937 engine(0);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 9);
  auto generator = std::bind(std::ref(dis), std::ref(engine));

  qDebug() << "First sequence: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    qDebug() << "Random value: " << generator();
  }

  engine.seed(0); // reset
  engine.discard(15); // discard the first 15 numbers from the first sequence
  qDebug() << "Last five numbers from first sequence: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    qDebug() << "Random value: " << generator();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Mersenne Twister can be represented as a (rather large) matrix over F<sub>2</sub> (the field containing the two elements 0 and 1). A transition to the next state is a multiplication by this matrix.

To jump to some arbitrary position in the stream you can compute the corresponding power of this matrix by repeated squaring, and multiply it with your initial state.

Comment: Is that practical? [This paper](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/ARTICLES/jump-seta-lfsr.pdf) linked from jHackTheRipper's answer seems to indicate that the matrix method requires too much memory, and a polynomial multiplication method is more feasible.

Answer (score -7):

I think what you are asking for would be against the definition of a cryptographically secure random number generator, so unfortunately I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It wouldn't be against the definition of a cryptographically secure generator (I think), and the Mersenne Twister is not a cryptographically secure random number generator (I know).

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning behind your first point please? You're correct that saying MT is not secure, my mistake :)

Comment: ... for example, consider the sequence `SHA256("secret seed" + n)` for n = 1, 2,... and `+` is string concatenation. That's not the usual way to create a PRNG using a secure hash function, so I'm not sure of its security properties, but I can't immediately see why it's insecure. It would have uniform distribution (as MT does), and would be random-access.

Comment: Wikipedia claims that a block cipher in CTR mode produces a secure PRNG (which makes sense, since if CTR is a valid mode to produce a keystream, it has to be a PRNG too). I think the same should apply with an irreversible function in place of a block cipher, although OFB is the usual way to build e.g. an SHA-PRNG.

Comment: It would go against the definition of a good random number generator - for a suitable definition of "good", and MT seems to meet most (all?) definitions. Or simply - if it was easy to get to a given point in the sequence, the algorithm wouldn't have so much internal state in the first place.

Comment: @phkahler: so are you saying that a secure block cipher used in CTR mode is *not* a good random number generator? What part of the definition of a good random number generator does it fail? I like your second point, though: all that internal state probably isn't *just* about speeding it up compared with some hypothetical random-access calculation. The main part of the definition of a *secure* PRNG that MT fails is that if you observe 624 outputs, you can predict the rest of the sequence forever. Distribution within short sub-sequences is good, though.

Comment: This discussion is getting interesting. I would humbly point out that "good" depends on the application. I am using it for stochastic simulations. In this case, having good statistical properties (TAOCP Vol II Chap 3) is sufficient. As opposed to cryptography, being a one-way function is not of importance here.

Comment: @subhacom: The reason I'm using such an extreme example (crypto) is just that if it doesn't violate that definition of a good PRNG, then it won't violate your weaker requirements either. Although looking back, I notice that a block cipher in simple CTR mode *isn't* necessarily a secure random number generator. The fact that it's a 1-1 map may mean that it produces statistically too few repeat outputs. e.g. a 64 bit block cipher with a 64 bit counter, then given 2^64-1 outputs, you can predict the next output with absolute certainty.

Comment: (Ignoring the fact that 2^64 is huge, I mean: in any case the bias against repeats would be detectable from far fewer outputs, at 2^36 or so you'd have a pretty shrewd idea something was up). As far as the actual question goes, though, I doubt that there is a random-access shortcut for the Mersenne Twister, because AFAIK it wasn't designed to have one. But I don't know for sure. It may be that there's an alternative PRNG you could use which has good distribution and also has this extra property (or at least has smaller state).

Comment: -1 The Mersenne Twister is not cryptographically secure, because it is linear.