# Jump ahead n random generations on the specific seed

Tags: python, random

I got this function which returns a set of random choices from a collection where I want the generation to be similar when called close in time (not actual time, just when the input variable time is close to what it was last time).
I have the implementation here in Python which works as expected, but Im not so satisfied with how I jump ahead using:

```
for _ in range(split):
    random.random()
```

This seems like a waste. **Is there no way of jump ahead N times as if random generated N values?** Or perhaps my algorithm should be completely different. Note that split could be very large.

```
def time_choices(collection: [], time: int, k: int, seed: int) -> []:
    seed_with_time = time // k
    split = time % k

    random.seed(seed + seed_with_time)
    for _ in range(split):
        random.random()
    first = random.choices(collection, k=k - split)

    random.seed(seed + seed_with_time + 1)
    second = random.choices(collection, k=split)

    return first + second
```

This could then be called like this:

```
for i in range(6):
    print(time_choices([
        "Anna", "Bruno", "Clara", "Dan", "Emma", "Fabian",
        "Sara", "Greta", "Hugo", "Iris", "Julia", "Kevin",
        "Lena", "Marco", "Nora", "Oscar", "Paula", "Quinn",
        "Rose", "Tor", "Uno", "Van", "Will", "Yuri", "Zoe"
    ], i, 4, 1337))
```

Example output:

```
['Oscar', 'Marco', 'Iris', 'Nora']
['Marco', 'Iris', 'Nora', 'Van']
['Iris', 'Nora', 'Van', 'Quinn']
['Nora', 'Van', 'Quinn', 'Sara']
['Van', 'Quinn', 'Sara', 'Paula']
['Quinn', 'Sara', 'Paula', 'Oscar']
```

Note how each name stays for the same amount of time. This function most of the time wont be called so often, with similar time parameter.

Comment: Python uses the Mersenne Twister algorithm, therefore this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184478/mersenne-twister-is-there-a-way-to-jump-to-a-particular-state

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047985/how-do-i-call-a-function-twice-or-more-times-consecutively